# what does this code do exactly? and what is 'number(2)' function?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, function, cursors

1.what exactly does this code do?
2.what is number(2)?

```
cursor c1 is    
select employee_id, department_id, commission_pct  from hr.employees; 
emprec c1%rowtype; 
v_hike  number(2);
begin 
open c1; 
loop 
   fetch c1 into emprec; 
   exit when c1%notfound;
   if  emprec.department_id = 40 then   v_hike := 10; 
   elsif emprec.department_id = 70 then   v_hike := 15;     
   elsif emprec.commission_pct > 0.30 then   v_hike := 5;
   else   v_hike := 10; 
end if; 


update employees set salary = salary + salary * v_hike/100  
where employee_id = emprec.employee_id; 
end loop; 
end;
```

Comment: where did you get it? what does the complete system do? you have no clue at all?

Comment: why have you tagged MySQL for a question on Oracle?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as mysql? Did you get this from [here](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/oracle/dec9/hrqueries.html)? Anyway... `number(2)` isn't a function, it's a [variable declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00202). Please familiarise yourself with the documentation to understand that and the rest of this code.

Comment: I got it from a lecture PPT, this was everything that was there about it.
I tagged mySQL by a mistake.
Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It's oracle cursor definition.. What exactly is that piece of sql doing is so hard to know how hard you can read it.

In first row you can see select which works with many set of rows.. Then you have define local variable. v_hike. In loop it's doing some expresions like count v_hike and then it's set new salary to employer

number(2) is incorrect write, it should be: number(p,s) where p-s digits before the decimal and s digits after the decimal..

Comment: `number(2)` is valid; the data type is [shown as `NUMBER[(p[,s])]` in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020), so it's valid to have `number`, `number(p)`, or `number(p,s)`.

Comment: Thanks Alex.. I have never noticed this fact :)

Comment: where p is precision, and s is scale.

Answer (score 0):

> what exactly does this code do?

**First of all, in Oracle PL/SQL, it is syntactically incorrect since you have missed the DECLARE keyword in your PL/SQL anonymous block. You will get a compilation error.**

Let me explain step by step :

```
cursor c1 is    
select employee_id, department_id, commission_pct  from hr.employees; 
emprec c1%rowtype;
```

It is an explicit cursor, it is a work area to store the processing information of the select query. And emprec is a collection type which will hold the resultset when you issue the FETCH statement.

> v_hike  number(2);

This is a variable declared of NUMBER data type. NUMBER(2) means it can hold a number value with PRECISION 2.

```
begin 
open c1; 
loop 
   fetch c1 into emprec; 
   exit when c1%notfound;
   if  emprec.department_id = 40 then   v_hike := 10; 
   elsif emprec.department_id = 70 then   v_hike := 15;     
   elsif emprec.commission_pct > 0.30 then   v_hike := 5;
   else   v_hike := 10; 
end if; 


update employees set salary = salary + salary * v_hike/100  
where employee_id = emprec.employee_id; 
end loop; 
end;
```

Next steps are,

- a. Open the cursor

  b. for each row in the cursor, loop through and prepare the
  collection in emprec

  c. When there are no records to fetch from cursor then exit

  d. Assign a number value to the v_hike variable based on the IF-ELSE
  construct.

  e. execute the UPDATE statement.

  f. Come out of loop.

  g. Scope of block ends with END keyword.